# Visual Studio debugger ignores methods when doing step-into

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I'm seeing some weird behaviour debugging my C# code - I cant post my exact code but essentially I have a partial abstract base class that defines an Execute method:

```
public abstract partial class MyBase
{
    public abstract void Execute();

    protect static object SomeMethod()
    {
        object aaa = OtherClass.GetObject();
        // etc...
    }
}
```

I then have another partial class which implements this method, and calls some static methods on the base class:

```
partial abstract class MyParent : MyBase
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        object myobj = SomeMethod();
        // etc...
    }
}
```

Both of these partial classes have are extensions of partial classes generated using xsd.exe from a schema.

What I'm seeing is that if I attempt to step-into my implementation of Execute(), the Visual Stuido debugger jumps through these methods - for example in this case it would step straight through to the `OtherClass.GetObject()` method.  The call stack still shows all the frames inbetween `Execute()` and `OtherClass.GetObject()`, and even lets me set them to be the active frame, however I can't do a line-by-line step through the code unless I place a breakpoint on each and every line.

- Why is this?
- How can I fix it so I can debug normally again!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xsd.exe typically decorates generated classes with the `DebuggerStepThrough` attribute, which means the debugger will .. well, you get the picture.

I've dealt with this in the past with a simple .vbs script that I call after invoking xsd.exe (typically as part of a pre-build step):

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(WScript.Arguments(0), ForReading)
strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close

strNewText = Replace(strText, 
    "[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]", "")

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(WScript.Arguments(0), ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine strNewText
objFile.Close
```

You call it with the name of the generated file as a parameter, as in:

`wscript.exe remove_attribute.vbs XsdGeneratedClasses.cs`

Answer (score 2):

Also, make sure the Just My Code checkbox is unchechedk, just in case.